# JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream returns a blank pdf when resultset is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jasper-reports

If I run the query and if it returns a null *resultset*, *JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream* returns a blank pdf but I want to display an error message instead of opening a download pop-up.

My java code is:

```
Connection con = null;  Statement stmt = null;  ResultSet rs = null;
OutputStream outStream = resourceResponse.getPortletOutputStream();
try{
    JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jrxmlPath,jasperPath);
    InputStream reportStream = getPortletConfig().getPortletContext().getResourceAsStream(jasperPath);
    Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/wpsdb", db2username, db2password);

    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    stringBuffer.append("select row_number() over(order by f.created_date) as \"SerialNo\"" +
                            ", f.name as \"File\", f.created_by as \"CreatedBy\", f.created_date as " +
                            "\"CreatedOn\", c.name as \"Category\",t.name as \"Tag\" " +
                            "from DMS.File f, DMS.Category c, DMS.Tag t where c.id=f.catid and t.id=f.tagid");

    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(stringBuffer.toString());

    if( !rs.next() ) {
                //handle the code to redirect to same page and display data not found message
    }
    else {
        JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);

                resourceResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
                resourceResponse.setProperty("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"DMS_File_Report.pdf\"");
                resourceResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, outStream, new HashMap(), resultSetDataSource); 
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

With ajax I am not able to open the pop-up, so I have used window.location.href instead. Here's my javascript part:

```
function genReport(){
         url = "<portlet:resourceURL id='generateReport'></portlet:resourceURL>";
         url +="?param1="+param1;
         window.location.href=url;
}
```

I don't want to save the file, I want it to be generated and downloaded on the fly without save to underlying disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a group in the report and in that section put "ERROR MESSAGE" then in  the 'Print when expression' put (Psuedocode) $F{rowNumber} == 0 or check something that shouldn't be null if resultSet was > 0. So when resultSet>0 then this section will not show. Else it will show.

For the second part can you do something like this:

```
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

    httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+name+".pdf");

    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager
            .fillReport(path+name + ".jasper",parameters,beanCollectionDataSource);


    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print,httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

Comment: I can check if resultset is not null and skip the above part but on the UI side I am using window.location.href which would be looking for some file or url and hence it is re-directed to new page (if resultset is null) showing blank page or "FILE NOT FOUND at this url .... etc".
I want to show same page with some error message...

Comment: @Priya I don't know if I am understanding correctly. So if resultset is null, show the PDF, that Jasper is filling, with an error message, and if the resultset is not null, show the  PDF with sections and data. And right now, is it showing a new PDF because of Jasper or because of window.href. Reason I ask because in Jasper there is an option if there is no data show a blank page. So I am wondering if it is genReport() or Jasper itself that is showing the blank page. If it is window.location.href, can you check (if the resultset is null) then redirect to an "error page"

Comment: I think the reason I am getting the blank pdf is because of Jasper (although I haven't set this option explicitly). Also, if resultset is null, I want to show error message on the same page itself, I _do_ _not_ want to redirect to a _new page_.

Comment: @Priya Can you check IReports and see what the "When no data" option says for the report, you can always change it. Just click on report name under Report Inspector, and open the Properties.

Comment: My problem is temporarily solved with an alternative. I am inserting the `"No Data" band` in my template in iReport. Thus, if query throws no data, this band allows me to generate a blank pdf with a message that I provide for the `"No Data Band"`. Yet, what I really want is _not_ to generate the pdf if no data found but just need to redirect to the same page with a message. I think the problem lies in `window.location.href`. Thanks a lot for all your help though, with it, my problem is solved temporarily(until/if the otherwise requirement occurs).